# Rails 3 :How to compare Datetime.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my Rails application I have a User model ,Department model, Group model and a Register model.User model has basic user information,

User Model:

```
id , name
has_and_belongs_to_many :departments , :groups
```

Department Model:

```
id,name
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
has_many :registers
```

Group Model:

```
id,name
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
has_many :registers
```

Register Model:

```
date ,department_id , group_id , one , two , three
belongs_to :department ,:group
```

Among the Register Model "one" , "two" , "three" are time slots say: 9-12 , 12-3 , 3-6.Every day each user has to mark attendance so that their attendance has to mark against the time slot in Register table. How to mark attendance based on current time with the time slot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to do

```
current_time = Time.now
if (9..11).include?(current_time.hour)
# Do A
elsif (12..14).include?(current_time.hour)
# Do B
elsif (15..18).include?(current_time.hour)
# Do C
end
```

(or)

```
current_time = Time.now
if (9...12).include?(current_time.hour)
# Do A
elsif (12...15).include?(current_time.hour)
# Do B
elsif (15...18).include?(current_time.hour)
# Do C
end
# I think of the extra "." as 'eating' the last value so you don't have it.
```

to deal with the overlaps

Comment: Thanks for the answer....What is (9..11) , (12..14) , (15..18)  in your above comment,what the above code actually do.

Comment: Is is the hour.  The construct `n1..n2` is a range.  It basically means, gives the the numbers 9, 10 and 11.  It includes the end points (9 and 11).  There is also a range that doesn't include the last digit.  Added this above.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
current_time = Time.now
if (9..12).include?(current_time.hour)
# 9-12
elsif (12..15).include?(current_time.hour)
# 12-3
elsif (15..18).include?(current_time.hour)
# 3-6
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Might consider creating a bitmap.  A 32 bit integer is lightweight and gives you 0-24, one for each hour.  Write some functions that can compare, set,... hour ranges.